# VS Studio Community 2019: Exception during code formatting of non-solution file

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting

I'm trying to edit code on a newly created `dotnet` project. The command that I use to create it is: `dotnet new console -o test`
After that I open up the folder `test` with vs studio and try to edit the defaultly created .cs file.
Unfortunately formatting of code (brackets, indents etc.) does not occur while typing.

Furthermore, trying to manually format code (using Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document or key bind combination) seems to throw the following exception (ActivityLog.xml):
`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: replaceSpan`

I've attached the full log [here](https://gofile.io/?c=10RJw8).

Additionally, I sometimes get these weird underlines at unconventional places as if there is an error. You can see them here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxoOM.jpg

Now, if I add the project to an existing solution using `dotnet sln add "mydir/test.csproj"` formating starts to work without any problems.

Could not find anything about this specific parameter or exception so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I've found the same thing if I switch from Solution View to Folder View and try running "Format Document" on some .cs files.

Comment: My stacktrace goes through
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Shared.Extensions.IWorkspaceExtensions.UpdateDocument(Solution solution, DocumentId id, IEnumerable`1 textChanges, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

... I'm guessing the solution is null or invalid in this case, and the UpdateDocument method doesn't handle that well.